# I have to reduce drawer menu item in drawable menu in android programatically

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

I have to reduce drawer menu item in drawable menu in android programmatically .Kindly suggest methods.I am attaching image also.

[image]

I have one app to debug, there are 7 menus in navigation-drawer menu .Out of  these menus I have to keep 2 menus only by writing java code .Can anybody suggest.

Comment: You can set visibility of menu item  as gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) activityMainBinding.toolbarActionbar);

        hideItem();/*Function declaration defined in outside of onCreate*/
}


 private void hideItem()
    {
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);//navigation_view is id declare in xml
        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.maps).setVisible(false);/* id of (maps,documents,reports,settings,logout) declare in drawer_menu.xml file*/
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.documents).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.reports).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.settings).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(false);
    }
```